# Load Records From EF Data Model in Custom/Predefined Order Using LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a comma delimited list of record id's:

```
 string = "2207,117,90,2168,120,118,113,112,17"
```

I need to be able to load the records those id's are associated with in the position that they are in that string.

Here is the code I am using to get my data using LINQ to EF with LINQ Methods:

```
 var styles = db.DataModel.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryTypeID == 5 && c.Enabled).OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

Is there anyway that the above query can be modified to get the records in the order that they are in the above list of record id's?

I am not sure how to do this. Any help/example would be greatly appreciated.

I am using LINQ Methods to EF 4.0 + C#

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort by the index in the input array after using `AsEnumerable()`:

```
var input = "2207,117,90,2168,120,118,113,112,17".Split(',');
var recordIds = Array.ConvertAll(input, int.Parse);

var styles = db.DataModel
                .Categories
                .Where(c => c.CategoryTypeID == 5 && c.Enabled && recordIds.Contains(c.ID))
                .AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(c => Array.IndexOf(recordIds, c.ID))
                .ToList();
```

Above assumes you want to load all `Category` objects that have an ID that is contained in `recordIds`. Once they are retrieved you order them by their index in the array.

Comment: Does `AsEnumerable()` cause the first part to be evaluated on the server?  I always thought you had to do `ToList()` in order to force loading.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` essentially will switch from an `IQueryable` that's in this case executed as SQL on the DB to an `IEnumerable` that's using Linq to Objects in memory - to enumerate all results you still do need `ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comma-separated list filter hack:

```
...Where(c => ("," + myString + ",").IndexOf("," + c.CatgeoryID + ",") != -1)...
```

Using a similar technique, you can get them back in the same order:

```
...OrderBy (c => ("," + myString + ",").IndexOf("," + c.CategoryID + ","))...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `Linq-to-objects` you can do the following:

```
int[] ids =  "2207,117,90,2168,120,118,113,112,17".Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();


var styles = from c in db.DataModel.Categories
             join i in ids on c.ID equals i
             where c.CategoryTypeID == 5 && c.Enabled
             select x;
```