# Load a few records from database given an array of integers and keep the order as the array without loading all records to memory

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an integer array `int[] ids` with length > 3000. I want to get top 15 records from a database table in the order of `Array.IndexOf(ids, recordId)`.

I am doing:

```
IQueryable<Record> records = from p in db.Records.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id)) 
                             select p;
records = records.ToList()
          .OrderBy(p => Array.IndexOf(ids, p.Id)).AsQueryable().Take(15);
```

This is highly inefficient because over 3000 records are loaded to memory while I only need 15.

Is there a way to solve the problem? Thank you.

Some existing posts:

[Load Records From EF Data Model in Custom/Predefined Order Using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914200/load-records-from-ef-data-model-in-custom-predefined-order-using-linq)

[Join array to EF query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398029/join-array-to-ef-query)

Comment: Is the items in ids already in some sort of sorted order? Would just sorting the records ID ascending or desending be an option?

Comment: @triad_Mike: No the items in ids are random got from a search engine tool I use. :(

Comment: Is there any guarantee that this query will only be run once at a time?

Comment: @SimonBelanger: The query will only be run once for each request in a web project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn it around.

1. Make the selection of ids from your array
2. Fetch only the records that you actually need
3. Project the fetched records back on your id selection/order.

Like this:

Given I have a list of 100 album id's. Take 15 of those id's, let's say, descending order.

```
var ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
var subsetOfIds = ids.OrderByDescending(i => i).Take(15);
var dbresults = Albums.Where(a => subsetOfIds.Contains(a.AlbumId)).ToArray();
var results = subsetOfIds.Select(id => new { IdFromArray = id, record = dbresults.First(album => album.AlbumId == id) }).ToArray();
```

Now I only fetched those 15 records from the database and still have them back in the  order that I want them to be.